# How to get rid of the Borders of a ContentDialog?

Tags: xaml, dialog, uwp

I can not display a ContentDialog without Borders. If I set  `BorderBrush="Transparent"` or  `BorderThickness="0 0 0 0"`  the Borders remain.

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ContentDialog displays, the properties of BorderBrush and BorderThickness are invisible. To create a border you need to specify custom content that has a border. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422445/border-for-contentdialog-in-windows-phone-8-1) can be helpful.

Besides, there are several other ways to do so:

1) As blueeyes said: You can take some trouble to modify the default ControlTemplate. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx) you can find explanations of ContentDialog's style and template

2) You can create an customized user dialog derived from ContentDialog, where you can define your own style. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) has a simple example.

Comment: I modified the BorderThickness and BorderBrush inside Border of the default ControlTemplate to `BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"` and
  `BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"`.Now I can set the thickness and color of the border  of the Dialog. Thanks.

Comment: i created custom class extend contentDialog, and added custom style and fixed issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with the `ControlTemplate`of it there you can change the whole style of it but I warn you just edit a copy of it and it will be a lot of work to do.

Hope my answer helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricks which works for me : when you define your `ContentDialog` (maybe in the code behind), you can override this resource :

```
Application.Current.Resources["ContentDialogBorderWidth"] = new Thickness(0);
```

I fund this resource on the style page of ContentDialog of Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx)